# How to calculate selected options in dropdowns inside gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a few dropdowns in my gridview, each has 2 same options, I want to calculate out of all these dropdowns how many times is option1 selected (selectedIndex = 1) and how many times the second option is selected (selectedIndex = 2) using jQuery.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gd1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onrowdatabound="gd1_RowDataBound" >
        <Columns>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="id"   Visible="False"/>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="fullName" Visible="True"  
        HeaderText="Full Name"/>
                      <asp:TemplateField >
                          <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>

                      <asp:TemplateField >
                          <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>

                      <asp:TemplateField >
                          <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>

                      <asp:TemplateField>
                          <HeaderTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Count1" runat="server" Text="First Count"></asp:Label>
                          </HeaderTemplate>
                          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="CountSelected1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>

                      <asp:TemplateField>
                          <HeaderTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="Count2" runat="server" Text="Second Count"></asp:Label>
                          </HeaderTemplate>
                          <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="CountSelected2" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

In the final 2 columns I want to display the total number of selections of option1 and option2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem my solution [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-calculate-selected-options-in-dropdowns-inside-gridview-using-jquery-4-9-2012)

final code that works:

```
var collection = $('select.ddlJ');

for (var element in collection)
$(element).change(function(){})

 $(function() {
    $('select.ddlJ').change(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td:last').prev().find('span').html( 
            $(this).parent().parent().find( 'select.ddlJ' ).filter(function() {
                return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'm';
            }).length
         );
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td:last span').html( 
            $(this).parent().parent().find( 'select.ddlJ' ).filter(function() {
                return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'n';
            }).length
         );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**First option:**
You can declare two global variables

```
var first=0;
var second=0;
```

and then do following:

```
$(function(){
    $("#selectBox").change(function(){
        switch($(this).val())
        {
            case "0": first++;
                      break;
 case "1": second++;
                      break;
        }
    });
});
```

this function is written for check box:

```
<select id="selectBox">
            <option value="0" id="first">FirstOption</option>
            <option value="1" id="second">SecondOption</option>
</select>
```

First option is not very good but fast solution.

**Second option:**

You can create jQuery widget that can count selections and then just wrap your check boxes using this widget. Here is example of widget (I copied it from someone's blog but lost link to get you source code, hope my example will be useful)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Green = {
        // Set up the widget
        _create: function () {
        },
        _init: function () {
            this.setLevel(this.getLevel());
        },
        getLevel: function () { return this.options.level; },
        setLevel: function (x) {
            var greenLevels = this.options.greenLevels;
            var level = Math.floor(Math.min(greenLevels.length - 1, Math.max(0, x)));
            this.options.level = level;
            this.element.css({ background: greenLevels[level] });
        },
        options: {
            level: 5,
            greenLevels: ['#000', '#010', '#020', '#030', '#040', '#050', '#060', '#070', '#080', '#090', '#0a0', '#0b0', '#0c0', '#0d0', '#0e0', '#0f0', '#fff']
        },
        darker: function () {
            this.setLevel(this.getLevel() - 1);
        },
        lighter: function () {
            this.setLevel(this.getLevel() + 1);
        },
        off: function () {
            debugger;
            this.element.css({ background: 'none' });
            this.destroy();
        },
        _setOptions: function () {
            $.Widget.prototype._setOptions.apply(this, arguments);
            this._refresh();
        }
    };

    $(function () {
        (function ($, undefined) {
            $.widget('ui.green', Green);
        })(jQuery);
    });

    function on() {
        $('.targetDiv').green(
            { level: 8,
                greenLevels: ['#000', '#00f', '#088', '#0f0', '#880', '#f00', '#808', '#fff']
            });
    }

</script>

<p class="targetDiv">
    This is a test div text.</p>
<input type="button" value="On" onclick="return on()" />
<input type="button" value="Lighter" onclick="$('.targetDiv').green('lighter');" />
<input type="button" value="Darker" onclick=" $('.targetDiv').green('darker');" />
<input type="button" value="Off" onclick=" $('.targetDiv').green('off');" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RowDataBound Event To declare Javascript function on Onchange Event of DropDown List as Follow...

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)                     
{                         
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {                           
    DropdownList drpLst = ((DropdownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl1"));
    Label lblCount2= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Count2");

    drpLst.Attributes["onchange"]="calculate(this,'"+lblCount2.ClientID+"');"                   

  }   
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var count=0;//This should be Global
function calculate(drpDownList,labelId) 
{
   if(drpDownList.selectedIndex==0)
     {
       count=count+1;
     }
  labelId.innerHTML=count;
}
```

Comment: this method is correct, but if there are 50 dropdown's there will be too many "if's"

Comment: no there will be only one if..as here we are passing dropdown as a object itself and the same function is called from every dropdown..so there is no need to write many ifs it will take care of count itself..so there will come only one if...

Comment: he calculates the count of all rows but I need my for every row

Comment: then use different approach..don't use global variable in javascript...my suggession is add hidden field in a template in your grid and send it along with dropdownlist in javascript function...and use that one to store count...you can think better apprach than that...